# How to stop all builds that are triggered on code commit in Circle CI

Tags: build, circleci

We have a project on github and a build is automatically triggered for every commit.

How to stop all builds that are triggered on code commit in App Circle. We would like to manually trigger the commits.

https://app.circleci.com/pipelines/github

Answer (score 1):

By default, CircleCI automatically builds a project whenever you push changes to a version control system (VCS). You can override this behavior by adding a `[ci skip]` or `[skip ci]` tag within the first 250 characters of the body of the commit or the commit’s title. This not only skips the marked commit, but also all other commits in the push.

e.g:

```
$ git log origin/master..HEAD

commit 63ce74221ff899955dd6258020d6cb9accede893
Author: Daniel Woelfel
Date:   Wed Jan 23 16:48:25 2017 -0800

    fix misspelling [ci skip]
```

Check: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/skip-build/

Answer (score 1):

A simple option that might solve your issue is enabling the Circle Project's Advanced Setting called "Only build pull requests". As the name implies, it will only trigger CI for each commit that is part of an open Pull Request. The default branch of the repo (usually master/main) will always trigger CI for every build.
If that is not enough for your needs, you could add a pipeline variable in your yml file that tells CI to skip a workflow. I.e:

```
version: 2.1

# Define the parameters we can inject from outside (i.e Circle's manual pipeline triggering, scheduled builds)
parameters:
  skip_tests:
    type: boolean
    default: false
  skip_deploy:
    type: boolean
    default: true
```

Then, on a particular workflow, you can use that variable to avoid running the associated jobs:

```
workflows:
  test_flow:
    unless: << pipeline.parameters.skip_tests >>
    jobs:
      - test:
  deploy_flow:
    unless: << pipeline.parameters.skip_deploy >>
    jobs:
      - deploy:
```

By combining these variables with the "Only build pull requests" option, you will still run tests when a PR is updated, but unrelated pushes will not trigger them. Also, no other branch (even the default branch) will run your deploy workflow, unless you call the pipeline from CircleCI API (or use the UI to manually trigger a pipeline and add the boolean parameter `skip_deploy` with a value of `false`. I.e:

[image: manually triggering a pipeline in Circle UI]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to prevent any commit push from triggering a build is to remove or disable (untick the `Active` box) the CircleCI webhook in the VCS repository settings.

Alternatively, you can choose to only disable the `Pushes` event in that webhook's settings, so other events (for example: pull-requests) can still trigger the webhook.